# Device or computer could not be verified

Tags: macos, mac, wifi

Recently I bought Macbook Pro Retina Early 2015, and after approximately one month my wifi shows

> No Wifi/Wireless device found

I rush to the iStore and submitted my macbook, they serviced it and returned it to me, after approximately 2 to 3 days the problem was back again and gone after 2 days. Since my wifi is working perfectly.

The problem I am facing is now when I open APP STORE and sign in there I get the following error message:

> Your device or computer could not be verified. Contact support for assistance.

I googled it search it on forums and got that its an issue of non registered network adapter. Kindly help me in this scenario is this a software bug or a hardware one or some effective solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had this problem. Not sure what exactly had helped, but I

- Went to the Network Preferences and deleted whatever I could, all the locations except the one left and for this last deleted all the interfaces.
- Rebooted
- In the Network Preferences created a new location.

After that everything started to work again. Probably you could just delete and recreate your Ethernet interface.

Answer (score 0):

I would try re-installing OS X to fix this.

To re-install OS X without losing files and without a DVD try these steps:

1. Shutdown computer.
2. Start up computer while holding the Command, Option, and R keys until you see a globe icon appear on the screen like [this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpeNw.jpg)
   *This may take a while, be patient.*
3. When a screen [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQu5l.jpg) appears, select "Reinstall OS X". Follow along with the instructions and in 1-2 hours you will have a new copy of OS X with all of your files and apps intact.

If the App Store works after re-installation, then please click the check-mark next to my post to mark it as the accepted answer. 
One of the awesome things about OS X is that you can re-install pretty easily without losing anything, some problems when you can't get them to go away can be fixed by re-installing. Remember these steps for later :)

Comment: Better read the described question. This doesn't look like the best suited answer to a typical hardware problem. Don't you think this full Mac OS X reinstall will just be a waste of time for our colleague already in trouble with a broken connection ?

Answer (score 0):

Happened same with me.
This is happening because the App Store is looking for a working connection on en0 port and it is not getting anything anything on it due to which it says the device cannot be verified.

- Your task is to switch the en0 and en1 assignments basically.
- Just copy the files 'preferences.plist' and 'NetworkInterfaces.plist' from `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration` to Desktop as a backup and delete it from `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`
- Restart your Mac and try to login into the App Store

Worked for me!